# Java: Doing one's own data type? (eg. long long double?)

Tags: java, precision, types

I'm just pondering about whether or not it's possible to create one's own data type?
So if you need more precision, that's not supported by one of the basic types, you could just "create" your own fullfilling your requierements.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: I would recommend you read about object oriented programming.  You can uses classes to define your own data types.

Comment: A user defined java class is also a type! Just add some members of types long, long  to hold whole and fractional parts of a number. Add methods to add/subtract and there you go!

Comment: @Andreas Hornig feel free to accept an answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers

And to answer your question - yes, you can crate data types, but they can't be primitive types (like `int`, `double`, etc). They have to be classes, just like the case with `BigDecimal` (and `BigInteger`)

And a further advice for using the `Big*` classes - as written, they are immutable. This means that calling `add(..)` doesn't change the object - it returns a new object that reflects the change. I.e.

```
BigDecimal dec = BigDecimal.ZERO;
dec.add(new BigDecimal(5)); // nothing happens
dec = dec.add(new BigDecimal(5)); // this works
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't create your own custom value types in Java, if that's what you're asking. You can, of course, create your own *reference* types - that's what every class in Java is, after all.

But as others have said, `BigDecimal` (and `BigInteger`) should be your starting points for numeric types with more precision.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be after the `BigDecimal` class:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

Everything is always possible.

That doesn't mean that somebody hasn't already done it before however, and much more efficiently than you ever will.

BigInteger and BigDecimal is what you're looking for.